# Get default button text/background colours in CSS/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

I saw an existing question, but the suggested answer was just hard-coded values for three different browsers. That may work on Windows/macOS, but I know from experience that FireFox on Linux uses GTK themes. So, some webpages that assumed that the background colour of an Input field was white, showed invisible text, because they had set the text colour black (black text on black background).

So, my question is, is there any way to get dynamic colour values for the default background/text of button? In Windows, there are ways to get such values. I am trying to add a button into a web page using a Chrome Extension (JavaScript), but possibly because of existing styles in the web page, if I do not specify the background colour with `.style`, the button's backround is white.